# Combining gradients from different "networks" in TensorFlow2

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to combine a few "networks" into one final loss function. I'm wondering if what I'm doing is "legal", as of now I can't seem to make this work. I'm using tensorflow probability :

The main problem is here:

```
# Get gradients of the loss wrt the weights.
gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [m_phis.trainable_weights, m_mus.trainable_weights, m_sigmas.trainable_weights])

# Update the weights of our linear layer.
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [m_phis.trainable_weights, m_mus.trainable_weights, m_sigmas.trainable_weights])
```

Which gives me None gradients and throws on apply gradients:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'device'

Full code:

```
univariate_gmm = tfp.distributions.MixtureSameFamily(
        mixture_distribution=tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=phis_true),
        components_distribution=tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=mus_true,scale=sigmas_true)
    )
x = univariate_gmm.sample(n_samples, seed=random_seed).numpy()
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x) 
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(64)  

m_phis = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
m_mus = keras.layers.Dense(2)
m_sigmas = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softplus)

def neg_log_likelihood(y, phis, mus, sigmas):
    a = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=mus[0],scale=sigmas[0]).prob(y)
    b = tfp.distributions.Normal(loc=mus[1],scale=sigmas[1]).prob(y)
    c = np.log(phis[0]*a + phis[1]*b)
    return tf.reduce_sum(-c, axis=-1)

# Instantiate a logistic loss function that expects integer targets.
loss_fn = neg_log_likelihood

# Instantiate an optimizer.
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

# Iterate over the batches of the dataset.
for step, y in enumerate(dataset):
    
    yy = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1)

    # Open a GradientTape.
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        
        # Forward pass.
        phis = m_phis(yy)
        mus = m_mus(yy)
        sigmas = m_sigmas(yy)

        # Loss value for this batch.
        loss = loss_fn(yy, phis, mus, sigmas)

    # Get gradients of the loss wrt the weights.
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, [m_phis.trainable_weights, m_mus.trainable_weights, m_sigmas.trainable_weights])

    # Update the weights of our linear layer.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [m_phis.trainable_weights, m_mus.trainable_weights, m_sigmas.trainable_weights]))

    # Logging.
    if step % 100 == 0:
        print("Step:", step, "Loss:", float(loss))
```

Comment: I guess you have two separate problems here. Let's first look into the `None` gradients. I do not believe that numpy functions propagate gradients. Thus I think `np.log` is a problem here, `tf.math.log` should do the same. Also you may consider decorating the function `neg_log_likelihood` with `@tf.function`. Where is `x` used?

Comment: @André thanks - I fixed the code to show where x is used - I pasted the code chunks badly

Comment: @André you were also right, replacing np with tf.math does produce gradients. Still have a problem with the 2nd line of apply_gradients

Comment: Can you split the training of the individual weights into separate calls of `apply_gradients`? So instead of once with `[m_phis.trainable_weights, m_mus.trainable_weights, m_sigmas.trainable_weights]`, call it three times with *one* single element of the list each.

Comment: @André yeah, I also need to split the gradients. It works, but kind of hacky. Is there no way to incorporate it?

Comment: Ah you can not use the same `gradients` for all calls? What error does it produce if you try? Let me know if it works without splitting, otherwise I will edit the answer below. In my eyes it's not really hacky to split the gradients. However, if you want a cleaner solution, you may want to write a `tf.Module` that actually captures all variables in a single place.

Comment: "InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match" if I don't use `gradients[0]`, etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer, in my eyes it should work that way. If there are any more issues with the answer, feel free to put a comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate problems to take into account.

### 1. Gradients are `None`:

Typically this happens, if non-tensorflow operations are executed in the code that is watched by the `GradientTape`. Concretely, this concerns the computation of `np.log` in your `neg_log_likelihood` functions. If you replace `np.log` with `tf.math.log`, the gradients should compute. It may be a good habit to try not to use numpy in your "internal" tensorflow components, since this avoids errors like this. For most numpy operations, there is a good tensorflow substitute.

### 2. `apply_gradients` for multiple trainables:

This mainly has to do with the input that `apply_gradients` expects. There you have two options:

First option: Call `apply_gradients` three times, each time with different trainables

```py
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(m_phis_gradients, m_phis.trainable_weights))
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(m_mus_gradients, m_mus.trainable_weights))
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(m_sigmas_gradients, m_sigmas.trainable_weights))
```

The alternative would be to create a list of tuples, like indicated in [the tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#apply_gradients) (quote: "grads_and_vars: List of (gradient, variable) pairs.").
This would mean calling something like

```py
optimizer.apply_gradients(
   [
      zip(m_phis_gradients, m_phis.trainable_weights),
      zip(m_mus_gradients, m_mus.trainable_weights),
      zip(m_sigmas_gradients, m_sigmas.trainable_weights),
   ]
)
```

Both options require you to split the gradients. You can either do that by computing the gradients and indexing them separately (`gradients[0],...`), or you can simply compute the gradiens separately. Note that this may require `persistent=True` in your `GradientTape`.

```
    # [...]
    # Open a GradientTape.
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        # Forward pass.
        phis = m_phis(yy)
        mus = m_mus(yy)
        sigmas = m_sigmas(yy)

        # Loss value for this batch.
        loss = loss_fn(yy, phis, mus, sigmas)

    # Get gradients of the loss wrt the weights.
    m_phis_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, m_phis.trainable_weights)
    m_mus_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, m_mus.trainable_weights)
    m_sigmas_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, m_sigmas .trainable_weights)

    # Update the weights of our linear layer.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(
        [
            zip(m_phis_gradients, m_phis.trainable_weights),
            zip(m_mus_gradients, m_mus.trainable_weights),
            zip(m_sigmas_gradients, m_sigmas.trainable_weights),
       ]
   )
   # [...]
```

Comment: I accept this for now, until there's a way to do it more concisely. Thanks!